# Tomboy error while tring to sync with Ubuntu one; Can anyone help?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

So I'm sure you've heard the song before, but after trying to sync my notes with Ubuntu One(on 10.10 AMD64) I get "Could not synchronize notes. Check the details below and try again." Of course the problem is that there are no details and trying again doesn't help. So I ran `tomboy -debug` and compared my error to any thing I could find about similar problems (such as the post [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/575937)) but found nothing useful.

Any way here's my first error, I got this using preferences>synchronization>Ubuntu_one

```
[ERROR 21:08:42.271] Synchronization failed with the following exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.NoteInfo.ParseJson (Hyena.Json.JsonObject jsonObj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.ParseJsonNoteArray (Hyena.Json.JsonArray jsonArray) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.ParseJsonNotes (System.String jsonString, System.Nullable`1& latestSyncRevision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetNotes (Boolean includeContent, Int32 sinceRevision, System.Nullable`1& latestSyncRevision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.GetNoteUpdatesSince (Int32 revision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The next thing I tried was using preferences>synchronization>tomboy_web with the default 'http://one.ubuntu.com/notes/' and got the same error plus one more.

```
[ERROR 21:12:31.949] System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.CheckDisposed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
   at System.Net.HttpListener.EndGetContext (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
   at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncPreferencesWidget.<OnAuthButtonClicked>m__1 (IAsyncResult localResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR 21:13:19.245] Synchronization failed with the following exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.DateTime.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.NoteInfo.ParseJson (Hyena.Json.JsonObject jsonObj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.ParseJsonNoteArray (Hyena.Json.JsonArray jsonArray) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.ParseJsonNotes (System.String jsonString, System.Nullable`1& latestSyncRevision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetNotes (Boolean includeContent, Int32 sinceRevision, System.Nullable`1& latestSyncRevision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.GetNoteUpdatesSince (Int32 revision) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I Have also tried removing then re-adding My computer from my Ubuntu One account, but that did not help either. The only other Thing I have noticed is that under system>preferences>ubuntu one >services, "Notes" is not listed as a service. I don't know if this is normal or not. Thanks for any help and please let me know if anything is confusing.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Could you please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+filebug?field.title=Another+Tomboy+error+while+tring+to+sync+with+Ubuntu+one)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for the time being My notes are syncing again. Turns out there was [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/709378) reported on launchpad that was the same as mine. The fix was some what annoying, but all I did was back up my local notes, delete all notes from the U1 server,restart tomboy, and try syncing again. It seems that editing a note from the U1 web interface can cause the errors above.

Comment: It didn't work for me.
I've removed and readded computer from account and it doesn't help too before I tried to remove my notes from Ubuntu One site.
What was helpful for me - cleaning and readding sync preferences in Tomboy. Problem began on laptop with 10.10 when I've installed 11.04 Beta 1 on PC. Upgrading laptop's Ubuntu to 11.04 release didn't help. Cleaning sync preferences did.